# how to use validation with onclick function

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I'm using jquery.validate plugin, here is my code I have tried

here is my HTML:

```
<div id="farmer-identity-add">
<label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Nama <font color="red">*</font></label>
<input class="form-control required" id="farmerName" name="farmer[name]" type="text" value="">
</div>
<button class="btn btn-outline btn-primary" id="btn-next-add" type="button">Selanjutnya <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

here is my jquery:

```
$('#btn-next-add').click(function(){
        $('#farmer-identity-add').validate({
            rules: {
                farmerName: {
                    required: true
                },
            },
            highlight: function(element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
            },
            unhighlight: function(element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
            },
            errorElement: 'span',
            errorClass: 'help-block',
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            }
        });
});
```

but i dont know what's wrong with my code, please help me.. thank you

Comment: Include form tag and give the form id to validate

Comment: my form got 4 part of section, just like wizard form, i want to make each section have validator.

Comment: This plugin validates the entire form. why don't you make separate form for each 4 sections ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is wrong with your code is you did not put your validation component into '`form`' also you must bind validation on the run-time, not inside button click. To use jquery validation library, you have to use '`form`' tag. Here is your updated code:

```js
$('#farmer-identity-add').validate({
  rules: {
    farmerName: {
      required: true
    },
  },
  highlight: function(element) {
    $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
  },
  unhighlight: function(element) {
    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
  },
  errorElement: 'span',
  errorClass: 'help-block',
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
      error.insertAfter(element.parent());
    } else {
      error.insertAfter(element);
    }
  }
});

$('#btn-next-add').click(function() {
  $('#farmer-identity-add').validate().element("#farmerName");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="farmer-identity-add">
  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Nama <font color="red">*</font>
  </label>
  <input class="form-control required" id="farmerName" name="farmer[name]" type="text" value="">
</form>
<button class="btn btn-outline btn-primary" id="btn-next-add" type="button">Selanjutnya <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

**UPDATE:**
Your second question:

> i got 4 section like farmer-identity-add inside my form. can i use
>   jquery validate to validate the data inside?

Answer: You can add each field like this:

```js
$('#farmer-identity-add').validate({
  rules: {
    farmerName: {
      required: true
    },
    farmerSurname: {
      required: true
    }
  },
  highlight: function(element) {
    $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
  },
  unhighlight: function(element) {
    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
  },
  errorElement: 'span',
  errorClass: 'help-block',
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
      error.insertAfter(element.parent());
    } else {
      error.insertAfter(element);
    }
  }
});

$('#btn-next-add').click(function() {
  $('#farmer-identity-add').validate().element("#farmerName");
  $('#farmer-identity-add').validate().element("#farmerSurname");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="farmer-identity-add">
  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Nama <font color="red">*</font>
  </label>
  <input class="form-control required" id="farmerName" name="farmer[name]" type="text" value="">
  <br>
  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Farmer Surname <font color="red">*</font>
  </label>
  <input class="form-control required" id="farmerSurname" name="farmer[surName]" type="text" value="">
</form>
<button class="btn btn-outline btn-primary" id="btn-next-add" type="button">Selanjutnya <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i got 4 section like farmer-identity-add inside my form. can i use jquery validate to validate the data inside?

Comment: For your question up there, this answer is correct. For your second question here, you can add your fields inside a single form, or if you validate them separately you can create multiple forms and bind validation methods for each at js side. If you need further details I can add them to my answer?

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check it out if good for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following syntax:

```
$('#form_id').validate({
    rules:{
        name : 
        {
            required: true
        },
        email : 
        {
            required: true,
            email : true
        },
        and so on
    },
    messages:{
        name : 
        {
            required: "message"
        },
        email : 
        {
            required: "message",
            email : "message"
        }
    }
});
```

You can add your custom validations into this method.

Comment: i got my form tag above.. this farmer-identity-add just 1 of 4 section inside that form, can i validate that section using jquery? thanks

Comment: The rule is simple just provide a unique id to form and input elements and call validate for each form like above example.